How strict is India about renouncing other citizenships?
Spain officially prohibits dual citizenship, but in practice it’s more of a pretense.  I would have to tell them I renounce, but USA doesn’t care and Spain knows that.
I’m just wondering whether it’s the same for India, or whether they demand proof one actually went through the US process.  Or something in between.
